# Git Cherry Pick dirty index

Tags: git

I have two branches master and exp

i tried to cherry pick some of the commit in the exp to master.I am getting
the following error.

```
git cherry-pick 209c4b154d3c15fa8086d4cc15fa34e53b8a65a3
fatal: Dirty index: cannot cherry pick
```

Can anyone explain this error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you have changes to your index (staged changes). either create a new commit or `git reset` the problematic files—whatever works best in your current situation

to avoid conflicts with changes in the working directory stash them away with `git stash save`, do the cherry-pick and then `git stash pop` them back. alternatively you can commit them and then cherry-pick